# LSTM network for multiclass classification of timeseries not obtaining good accuracy

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, multiclass-classification

I have developed a LSTM network for multi-class classification of timeseries. The timeseries contains 15 columns (features) and 6 classes (labels) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Features include the 3-phase currents of 5 transmission lines connected to a power system bus. Thelabels show the state of the system whether it is the Normal state (0) of the system or there is short-circuit fault in a transmission line (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Labels are one-hot-encoded. The code is as follows:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed, RepeatVector, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import to_categorical


# Define the directory where your Excel files are stored
data_directory = '/Users/hosseinebrahimi/Documents/ThesisResults/Normal/NEW/*.xlsx'
data_directory1 = '/Users/hosseinebrahimi/Documents/ThesisResults/Normal/NEW/test/*.xlsx'


# Use glob to get a list of file paths matching a pattern
file_paths = glob.glob(data_directory)
file_paths1 = glob.glob(data_directory1)

# Initialize empty lists to store data and labels
data_list = []
labels_list = []
data_list1 = []
labels_list1 = []

# Load the first 5% of the data from each Excel file into a dataframe
for file_path in file_paths:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, dtype=np.float64)  # Specify the dtype as float
    num_rows = len(df)
    sample_size = int(num_rows * 1)  # Use 20% of the data
    # Extract features (data) and labels
    data = df.iloc[:sample_size, 1:-3].values
    labels = df.iloc[:sample_size, -2].values
    
    # Append data and labels to the lists
    data_list.append(data)
    labels_list.append(labels)

for file_path1 in file_paths1:
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file_path1, dtype=np.float64)  # Specify the dtype as float
    num_rows1 = len(df1)
    sample_size1 = int(num_rows1 * 1)  # Use 20% of the data
    # Extract features (data) and labels
    data1 = df1.iloc[:sample_size1, 1:-3].values
    labels1 = df1.iloc[:sample_size1, -2].values
    
    # Append data and labels to the lists
    data_list1.append(data1)
    labels_list1.append(labels1)



# Concatenate data and labels into a single NumPy array
X = np.concatenate(data_list, axis=0)
y = np.concatenate(labels_list, axis=0)
X1 = np.concatenate(data_list1, axis=0)
y1 = np.concatenate(labels_list1, axis=0)

# Encode class labels
# one hot encode y
y = to_categorical(y) 
y1 = to_categorical(y1)
print(X.shape, y.shape, X1.shape, y1.shape)



X_train = X
y_train = y
X_test = X1
y_test = y1

# Normalize the data
#scaler = StandardScaler()
#X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
#X_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

# Reshape the data to be suitable for LSTM input (sequence length, features)
n_features = X_train.shape[1]
sequence_length = 1  # You can adjust this based on your data

truncate_train = int(X_train.shape[0]-(X_train.shape[0]%sequence_length))
n_samples_train = int(X_train.shape[0]/sequence_length)

truncate_test = int(X_test.shape[0]-(X_test.shape[0]%sequence_length))
n_samples_test = int(X_test.shape[0]/sequence_length)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train[:truncate_train], (n_samples_train,sequence_length, n_features))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test[:truncate_test], (n_samples_test, sequence_length, n_features))

#y_train = np.reshape(y_train[:truncate_train], (n_samples_train,sequence_length, 6))
#y_test = np.reshape(y_test[:truncate_test], (n_samples_test, sequence_length, 6))


# fit and evaluate a model
def evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
 verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 20, 50
 n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], y_train.shape[1]
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features), return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
 model.add(BatchNormalization())
 model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
 model.add(BatchNormalization())
 model.add(Dense(200, activation='tanh'))
 model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
 # fit network
 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
 # evaluate model
 _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
 return accuracy
 
# summarize scores
def summarize_results(scores):
 print(scores)
 m, s = np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)
 print('Accuracy: %.3f%% (+/-%.3f)' % (m, s))
 
# run an experiment
def run_experiment(repeats=1):
 # load data
 #X_train = , y_train, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()
 # repeat experiment
 scores = list()
 for r in range(repeats):
     score = evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
     score = score * 100.0
     print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))
     scores.append(score)
 # summarize results
 summarize_results(scores)
 
# run the experiment
run_experiment()
```

The `MinMaxScaler` corrupts the data and the `StandardScaler` does not make a signficance.

I'm getting an accuracy around 75% at max which is not suitable at all.
I will appreciate tips and code improvement guidance.

Comment: Would you provide your train/test data shapes, model summary, and the learning curves of the accuracy during training.

Comment: There are 1668341 timesteps in training and 417035 timesteps in test sets. The shape of (1668341, 15) and (417035, 15) are evaluated. However, the 60 timesteps sequences are also used (27805, 60, 15), (6950, 60, 15) which didn't improve the performance.

Comment: This sequence length could be a hyper-parameter, meaning you should try other values than 60. But one think also, would you try to remove the BatchNormalization in your model, I don't think it functions well with LSTM.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Actually, I removed it and yes it didn't have any impact on the performance. I will try to change the sequence length as you suggested.